# Migrate Biztalk ports to new server

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010, biztalk2006r2

I am working on a Biztalk application that has been migrated from 2006 to 2010. What hasn't been recreated are the send and receive ports. Recreating the ports is proving to be tedious. Is there a way to migrate them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right-click the application and choose Export -> Bindings.

This will create an XML file with all of the configuration (minus passwords!) on your disk.
Move it to the new server and then right click your application again and choose Import -> Bindings.

This XML file also includes orchestration bindings, schema tracking and so on.
If you just want send/receive ports, delete everything from the XML file that you do not need.

Important: be sure to have the correct adapters/hosts configured before importing the bindings, or you WILL get errors!

Comment: Just to add to Pieter's answer, when you import Bindings you will overwrite any existing Receive Ports/Locations and Send Ports with the values in the Binding file if they already exist on the target environment.